# Rails tutorial - exception reentered error in development when I add image upload validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, development-environment

**UPDATE**
I noticed this morning the following listing a little higher up in the heroku log:

```
excon.error.response
2016-11-06T18:17:48.973789+00:00 app[web.1]:   :body          => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-west-1'</Message><Region>us-west-1</Region><RequestId>...</RequestId><HostId>...</HostId></Error>"
```

After adding `:region => ENV[’S3_REGION’]` to my fog credentials, then running `heroku config:set S3_REGION=us-west-1` at the command line, picture uploads are working in production! So about half of my problems are solved - I still don't understand completely why the create action was causing me problems both in production and in development - especially given the entirely different configurations of the two environments. My suspicion is that, in development, `if @micropost.save` was causing problems because the error was a few layers removed - in Amazon's web services. I don't have a clear answer to this question, but I'm going to mark it resolved - effectively, it is.

I'm nearing the end of Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, and just as I come to the end of implementing image uploads to the user microposts, I'm getting a very cryptic error: exception reentered.

It seems to think the problem is in my create action under the microposts controller:

```
 def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
...
  private

  def correct_user
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
  end
```

Specifically, it highlights the `if @micropost.save` line.

Now, after finding little help online, I used my rudimentary paste-Michael's-code-over-my-code technique, and, amazingly, I got the error to disappear. I narrowed it down to the micropost model, this causes a problem:

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validate  :picture_size

  private

   # Validates the size of an uploaded picture.
   def picture_size
    if picture.size > 5.megabytes
      errors.add(:picture, "should be less than 5MB")
    end
   end
end
```

This does not:

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validate  :picture_size

  private

    # Validates the size of an uploaded picture.
    def picture_size
      if picture.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:picture, "should be less than 5MB")
      end
    end
end
```

Is this an issue of indentation? I don't know. Anyway, so I moved on to deployment with Amazon web services and heroku, and I encountered another error, this entry in my heroku logs stuck out:

```
2016-11-06T04:53:11.814607+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-11-06T04:53:11.814544 #10] FATAL -- : [...]   
2016-11-06T04:53:11.814575+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2016-11-06T04:53:11.814575+00:00 app[web.1]:   :status_line   => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
2016-11-06T04:53:11.814662+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-11-06T04:53:11.814615 #10] FATAL -- : [...] app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

So I can't just wipe my hands clean and move on. This constitutes my question:
-broadly speaking, what is the "exception reentered" error?
-is my indentation theory plausible?
-any idea how I might fix this.

Thank you so much, I'm very green, so let me know if you need more information (and be patient if this turns out to be a stupid mistake).

For reference, the full micropost controller:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  private

  def micropost_params
    params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :picture)
  end

  def correct_user
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
  end  

end
```

Comment: Please post micropost controller

Comment: can you run locally and show the full stack trace? it's waay harder to debug on production boxes

Comment: @RajarshiDas - I added the controller.

Comment: @maxpleaner - Unfortunately, I can't get the error back in my development server!

Comment: where is the "exception reentered" error? you dont show it in the question

Comment: @maxpleaner ah, I apologize, so I'm just recounting from memory the error I got running the app on my rails server. I got the big red rails errors page, headed with "microposts_controller#create", and then the problem code reproduced below.

Comment: you're new to StackOverflow so it's admissible to not know this, but if your question is about an error than you absolutely need to show the original error, including all those lines of text that don't look like useful details. Just copy and paste the "big red rails error page" into your question.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to go ahead and close the question - I don't think I can reasonably expect to get an answer given the information I have to make available.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE I noticed this morning the following listing a little higher up in the heroku log:

```
excon.error.response
2016-11-06T18:17:48.973789+00:00 app[web.1]:   :body          => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-west-1'</Message><Region>us-west-1</Region><RequestId>...</RequestId><HostId>...</HostId></Error>"
```

After adding `:region => ENV[’S3_REGION’]` to my fog credentials, then running heroku config:set `S3_REGION=us-west-1` at the command line, picture uploads are working in production! So about half of my problems are solved - I still don't understand completely why the create action was causing me problems both in production and in development - especially given the entirely different configurations of the two environments. My suspicion is that, in development, `if @micropost.save` was causing problems because the error was a few layers removed - in Amazon's web services. I don't have a clear answer to this question, but I'm going to mark it resolved - effectively, it is.